# RxDart BehaviorSubject confusion

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I have been using RxDart along my Flutter projects for a while. However I find it confusing that defining a `BehaviorSubject` you can listen directly to the subject, and also to the subject's stream. I wasn't really able to point out the difference.

*Example*:

```
BehaviorSubject<String> _mySubject = BehaviorSubject();

_mySubject.listen((value) => { print('Logging $value'} );
_mySubject.stream.listen((value) => { print('Logging $value'} );
```

Furthermore, BehaviorSubjects seem to offer two ways to access the last emitted value, from the docs I see the `value` getter which is synchronous. As well as the `last` getter returning a `Future`.

Once again I am confused. If nothing was emitted, then why isn't the `value` getter returning null? Instead, it just waits. The only workaround I found was to seed the subject with a null value.

Finally, I tried using the `last` getter as a Future and it never returns. Wether there is data or not. Calling it on the Subject just never seems to work.

**EDIT:**

Thanks @pskink for pointing out that the `stream` getter returns the `Subject` itself, therefore no difference between my two first examples.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/blob/master/lib/src/subjects/behavior_subject.dart#L126

Comment: @pskink thanks for pointing that out. So they're exactly the same thing. Good to know.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` should return null if nothing has been emitted yet, not sure why it didn't work for you. Which version of RxDart are you using?

`last` on the other hand works a bit different. It will return the last value of a Stream after the Stream has been closed. So you need to call _mySubject.close(); then the Future will be completed (as long as the Stream has emitted any value, otherwise there will be an error).